# Evaluate Single Python Code Blocks in a Quarto File like in R Studio or Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, r, literate-programming, polymode, quarto

[Quarto](https://quarto.org/) is a literate programming framework. It allows you to combine in a single file code (in various programming languages) and text (in markdown).<sup>*</sup>

When a Quarto document is rendered, the output from the code is combined with the text into a single document (e.g. pdf or html).

I have installed `Quarto-emacs`, which does a great job of rendering and live-previewing quarto files. Among other things, I have also installed `Polymode`, which associates different code and text blocks with their respective major-modes in a single buffer. Now I can write, code, and preview the results on the fly. Thanks, Emacs!

[image: Literate programming with live preview side-by-side]

However, whenever I change some python code block, I have to re-render the whole document (by running `markdown-preview` or `markdown-compile`). This can take a while. Moreover, I can't run the code block and then continue to experiment in the interpreter (REPL).

So **what I want is to run only a selected python code block** or the selected and all previous code blocks (like in a Jupyter notebook) **in the interpreter** (REPL). This works quite well in [RStudio](https://posit.co/), but I would rather stick to Emacs, which in general has great support for Python and R.

It sort of works with R code blocks in Emacs. When I hit `C-c b` (`ess-eval-buffer`) on an R code block, a buffer with an R console is opened and the block is executed there. I don't know how to evaluate all previous code blocks, however.

But when I hit `C-c c` (`elpy-shell-send-buffer`), the whole buffer is evaluated instead of just the present code block. Of course, this results in a syntax error. When I try `C-c C-y w` `elpy-shell-send-codecell`, I get "Not in a codecell".

I also tried several `polymode` [functions](https://polymode.github.io/usage/):

- `polymode-eval-region-or-chunk` produces `Undefined ‘polymode-eval-region-function’ in buffer test.qmd[python]` on python blocks but works on R blocks.
- `polymode-eval-buffer`, `polymode-eval-buffer-from-beg-to-point`, and `polymode-eval-buffer-from-point-to-end` only run the R blocks, not the Python blocks.

Is there any way to make this work as seamlessly as in RStudio?

<sup>*This is a generalization of [R Markdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) and similar to both `org-mode` with `org-babel` and [Juypter](https://jupyter.org/) notebooks, which Emacs can display and run using `ein`.</sup>

Comment: You mention that you can 'preview results on the fly'? So why you (also) have to re-render the document using `markdown-preview`? According to the [Quarto documentation](https://quarto.org/docs/get-started/hello/text-editor.html#authoring) you should only have to save the file to update the 'preview'.

Comment: @dalanicolai `Quarto-emacs` doesn't preview on file save. See here: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-emacs/issues/5

Comment: Ah yeah, I am just testing now, and noticed it. However, the 'preview update on save' does work when starting the preview from the terminal (that is not so much work, and you only have to do it once). It is a good workaround for now.

Comment: You mean that `ess-eval-buffer` works from the .qmd file buffer? Here it does open an R console, but it sends the whole buffer contents instead of the only code block.

Comment: Okay, it got fixed after installing poly-R separately.

Comment: That's interesting. Yes, I have poly-R installed, and it sends only the cell/block at point.

Comment: The workaround is indeed useful for getting around the inconvenience of having to run markdown-preview. Thanks! What I find more important, however, is to be able to execute a code block directly in the interpreter/REPL, because then I can experiment with the current state of the script, its variables etc.

Comment: I have found how to do it, without elpy. You can try if it works with elpy also.

Comment: This would be awesome. Looking forward to your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT

Probably a cleaner way than the original answer is to just define a suitable `polymode-eval-region-function`. Inspecting again `poly-R.el`, we find that we can define an appropriate function as follows:

```lisp
(defun poly-python-eval-region (beg end msg)
    (python-shell-send-region beg end nil msg t))

(defun poly-python-mode-setup ()
  (setq-local polymode-eval-region-function #'poly-python-eval-region))

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'poly-python-mode-setup)
```

Make sure to evaluate the above code before opening the quarto file, as it configures the `polymode-eval-region-function` via the `python-mode-hook`.

Also, make sure that you start a python shell (by placing your cursor within the python cell and doing `M-x run-python`) before calling `polymode-eval-chunk`.

Subsequently, you should do `M-x polymode-eval-chunk` from within a python code block, and then Emacs will correctly make use of the `poly-python-eval-region` function.

END EDIT

Although I haven't tested this with elpy, I guess it should work when using elpy also. From poly-R.el, we find that the region is narrowed by advising `ess-eval-buffer` (and similar functions) with `pm-execute-narrowed-to-span`.

However, we can not simply advise `python-shell-send-buffer` because the `save-restriction` within that function breaks the 'effect' of the advice.
We can solve it by defining a custom `my-python-shell-send-buffer`:

```lisp
(defun my-python-shell-send-buffer (&optional send-main msg)
  "See docstring python-shell-send-buffer."
  (interactive (list current-prefix-arg t))
  (python-shell-send-region (point-min) (point-max) send-main msg t))

(advice-add 'my-python-shell-send-buffer :around 'pm-execute-narrowed-to-span)
```

Now, with the cursor placed inside a python code block, we can simply send the block via `M-x my-python-shell-send-buffer` (or bind it to some shortcut).

Before we can use this, we first have to do `M-x run-python` from the .qmd file buffer (but I guess you know that already).

Beware that `python-shell-send-buffer` only prints output (i.e. from print statements), not return values. But, when sending your example code block, the plot should show 'pop-up '.

Comment: Many thanks for this. I won't be able to test this before the week-end, but I'll accept the answer, of course, if it works

Comment: Again, thanks for your suggestion! Unfortunately, the original solution (`my-python-shell-send-buffer`) results in: `(anonymous nil t): Wrong number of arguments: (2 . 4), 5 [M-x pm-debug-mode RET for more info]` The new solution results in: `poly-python-eval-region: Wrong number of arguments: (2 . 4), 5`.

Comment: Strangely, for the new solution `poly-python-eval-region` actually remains unchanged. I get `The mark is not set now, so there is no region`. If instead I call `poly-mode-eval-chunk`, i get `poly-python-eval-region: Wrong number of arguments: (2 . 4), 5`, as described above.

Comment: I'm sure this is my mistake. Too bad it's not obvious for me how to fix it.

Comment: Both elpy-mode and Python-mode are active.

Comment: Are you sure that you are trying the `poly-python-eval-region` function as printed above? Because that error message says that it expects 2-4 arguments, while the function above expects exactly 3 arguments (i.e. (3 . 3)). Also, it says the function gets passed 5 arguments, while in `polymode-eval-chunk` the function is called with 3 arguments. So I am not sure what is happening there. Could you check if you find the following line at the end of `polymode-eval-chunk` its body: `(funcall polymode-eval-region-function (nth 1 body-span) (nth 2 body-span) msg)`? (You can use `M-x find-function`)

Comment: Weird, thanks for the hint. The end of `polymode-eval-chunk` looks exactly as you describe it. I'll experiment some more.

Comment: I tried this on a vanilla configuration, only with quarto-mode, ess, poly-mode, poly-r, and poly-markdown installed. Still: Your new solution results in `poly-python-eval-region: Wrong number of arguments: (2 . 4), 5` whenever I call `M-x polymode-eval-region` in a python code-block. Your original solution results in `(anonymous nil t): Wrong number of arguments: (2 . 4), 5 [M-x pm-debug-mode RET for more info]` when I call `my-python-shell-send-buffer` in a python code-block.

Comment: By the way, regardless which polymode-function from the list in my original post I call, the last part of the error message (behind the name of the function) is always the same, `Wrong number of arguments: (2 . 4), 5`.

Comment: Ah sorry, I see now, I forgot to mention that the `polymode-eval-region-function` is used by `poly-mode-eval-chunk` (although it looks like you tried that before already). Also, you should evaluate the code before you open the quarto file as the function is set/configured via the hook. I've added usage instructions to the 'EDIT' part. Hope that solves the problems...

Comment: Never mind, I figured out the hook has to be called first. Here's what worked for me: I left two of the arguments out of the call to `python-shell-send-region` within your first function, e.g. I changed it from `(python-shell-send-region beg end nil msg t)` to `(python-shell-send-region beg end msg))`. Thanks so much for solving the first 99% for me!

Comment: Ah great! It is strange that you get this message `poly-python-eval-region: Wrong number of arguments: (2 . 4), 5`, as it should have mentioned the `python-shell-send-region` function (as that is the one that expects (2 . 4) arguments but receives 5). This reminds me that I should check my answers on other Emacs version, I am using Emacs 29, which I guess is why things behave different here. Will check it later and update the answer then...

Comment: My emacs version is 27.1. Maybe that explains it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips guys! I just installed quarto-mode today and trying it out now. Your solution is useful and has allowed me to run the Python code in a shell. However, the display of the input is slightly weird for me:

[image: Python shell]

As you can see, the output is there, but the input is weirdly formatted. Do you have the same?

In addition, were you able to get LSP (via eglot or lsp-mode) properly working? I am using eglot and ran into some issues: https://github.com/joaotavora/eglot/issues/1229

Quarto looks great, and quarto-mode looks useful even though it's still relatively new (and unfortunately inactive in terms of development). I'm keen to understand how you deal with these issues and how you use quarto as I'd like to stay with Emacs for this as well.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/24463)